# Export compliance TestFlight?

Tags: ios, testflight

When I about to start a TestFlight for an app I get the following:

Export Compliance

Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS or macOS.)

The only thing my app uses is Keychain, what to answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine to submit your app without needing export compliance checked. I have a few apps, ones with keychain access and I did not use it which was approved. I did need it for using HTTPS/SSL for another APP.

Comment: Oh, so if the app uses HTTPS to communicate with a webservice, it's needed?

Comment: Yes, it seems pretty clear in the definition that even using standard https to communicate with a web service it is needed.